# Can't use winscard.h in a UWP app due to WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP blocks

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10-universal, smartcard

I'm developing in C++ a Universal Windows Platform app. I have a **working** project in C++ which can communicate with smart cards. For this communication it uses the `winscard.h` library.

I'd like to use in the UWP app this functions provided by the `winscard.h`, but I can't compile it in the UWP. After some research I found that in this header file there is a condition:

`#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)`

So this is the reason the compiler doesn't found the methods. Going forward I wanted to change this `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION` to the `WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP` but I found nothing about this.

I set in the appxmanifest file the `TargetDeviceFamily` name to `Windows.Desktop`, but it doesn't help.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to change the `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION`?
   If not:
2. Can I use the `winscard.h` lib in UWP app?

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292199/when-does-if-winapi-family-partitionwinapi-partition-desktop-in-dxvahd-h-micr?

Comment: Yes, of course but it didn't helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP` guard means the API is not supported for UWP apps. It is trivial to unblock the compiler, but it's not a good idea.

- You could unblock the compiler by making the declarations visible, but then you'd have problems linking.
- You could manually add the correct import lib to link, but then it would likely fail at runtime due to security checks.
- Even if you managed to make that work, your app would not be allowed in the Windows Store.
- Even if you get it working and don't care about the Windows Store, this is not a supported scenario and could break at any point in time.

The correct way to do this is with the types in the `Windows.Devices.SmartCards` namespace. If there are features missing from that API, you can send feedback via [UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform?query=smartcard) or the Feedback Hub.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I was afraid to start from the beginning with that namespace, but I should :)